# how to change class variable and save this variable

Tags: php, laravel

route/web.php

```
Route::post("/setBestBook",function(Request $request){
    Books::setBestBook($request->book);
    return "Your best book have been added";
});


Route::get("/BestBook",function(){
    return (Books::getBestBook().gettype(Books::getBestBook()));
});
```

Books Class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Books{

    public static $BestBook;

        static function setBestBook($book){

        static::$BestBook=$book;

    }

    static function getBestBook(){

        return static::$BestBook;

    }

}
```

I want when someone sends a favorite book, the server saves the name of the book, but not in the database

Comment: PHP is stateless, static property values are not maintained across page loads. If you want to save something across page loads (and/or different visitors) and you don’t want to use a database, choosing an alternative depends on several things: is the favorite book user-specific (can it be stored in a cookie, session or the browser’s localstorage, or should it be the same for that user on different devices)? Or can any user upload a new one that replaces whatever value was there before, where that new favorite now counts for all users?

Comment: I want any user can upload a new one that replaces whatever value was there before

Comment: Then you will need some kind of server-side storage. A database would be the most logical solution, but not the only one. An alternative could be to write it to a file. That’s fairly easy to implement in your `Books` class. If your site is going to have a lot of users simultaneously you might need to think about file locking techniques, but I wouldn’t bother initially.